# Curve- and Array Modifier won't align with the curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am a bit desparate with one problem. I am having a bezier curve, which I want to add some meshes to with the array modifier, in combination with the array modifier. Problem is, no matter which axis I use, or where I put the origin of either the curve, or the arrayed object, it is far from aligned with each other. In the picture I put in the origin of both is at the very beginning of the bezier curve, I also had both in the mass center of the curve, with similar result. Also, I tried  to copy the curve and tried it with the other curve, with no success.

Thanks for the attention and I look forward to hear some fresh thoughts to this matter.[image]

Comment: could you please share the object + curve?

Comment: thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I actually didn't find this particular thread before! It helped a lot and everything works fine now. :)

Comment: @moonboots do you still want object and curve? If so, how do I share those? Never done that before.

Comment: yes please do it on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/